# Powershell using C# code from Add-Type crashes shell (SystemParamtersInfo)

Tags: c#, powershell, winapi

I'm trying to write a script that toggles mouse properties for me on execution ... but I can't get past the process to query some of the attributes.  I'm not a C# programmer and only a budding Powershell scripter but I have experience in other scripting languages ... this has the feeling of me just having done something dumb.

Executing the script below causes a crash, with very little useful information.... so my first question, I guess, is this: *is there some way to get better information as to why my script crashed powershell?*

As far as doing this other ways, I already tried munging the registry, but I don't want to require a restart to to apply the settings (this is more or less a quick way for me to toggle a setting on and off once I get it squared away)...  As far as I've read so far, SystemParametersInfo (from user32) is the way to do it, but I don't have a C# IDE or the means to compile programs in C#, and would rather use powershell if it's not too cumbersome.

Additionally, it seems that using the `ref int lpvParam` version of the SPI imported call works (I used it with SPI_GETMOUSESPEED) but the `ref int[] lpvParam` version does not..  *Maybe it's the function definition that's being problematic?*  *I assumed that I'd need to import it multiple times and overload it, but maybe this is wrong?*  Replace the function call at the end to test this -- use `$mouse.spiGetMouseSpeed`

MS's documentation (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724947) suggests that there are multiple varible types that can go in for `lpvParam` so I figured overloading it was the way to go...

Here's the code.

```
#https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724947

Add-Type @"
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Microsoft.Win32;

namespace Enigma
{
    public class Mouse {
        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
            private static extern int SystemParametersInfo(
                int uAction, 
                int uParm, 
                ref int lpvParam, 
                int fuWinIni);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
            private static extern int SystemParametersInfo(
                int uAction, 
                int uParm, 
                ref int[] lpvParam, 
                int fuWinIni);

        private const int SPI_GETMOUSE = 0x0003;
        private const int SPI_GETMOUSEHOVERHEIGHT = 0x0064;
        private const int SPI_GETMOUSEHOVERTIME = 0x0066;
        private const int SPI_GETMOUSEHOVERWIDTH = 0x0062;
        private const int SPI_GETMOUSESPEED = 0x0070;
        private const int SPI_GETMOUSETRAILS = 0x005E;
        private const int SPI_GETMOUSEWHEELROUTING = 0x201C;

        public int[] spiGetMouse() {
            int[] res = new int[3];
            SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETMOUSE, 0, ref res, 0);
            return res;
        }

        public int spiGetMouseSpeed() {
            int res = 0;
            SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETMOUSESPEED, 0, ref res, 0);
            return res;
        }
    }
}

"@

$mouse = New-Object Enigma.Mouse

# This function call fails and crashes PowerShell ISE
$mouse.spiGetMouse()

exit
```

Comment: Try `int[] lpvParam` instead of `ref int[] lpvParam`.

Comment: IT WORKED.  So ... then why does this work?  Also, then, why do I need `ref int lpvParam` for the other one? (straight up `int lpvParam` doesn't write the value to the var when called)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arrays are reference types in .NET, so them does not need additional `ref` qualifier to be passed by reference. Thus you should use `int[] lpvParam` instead of `ref int[] lpvParam`. `int` (`System.Int32`) is a value type, so it have to have `ref` qualifier to be passed by reference.